# javascript 'this' code for chaining

Tags: javascript, methods, this

I am trying to develop a library like jQuery that allows chaining.  I already have functions that work, but I need to chain them together.  Please review the code below and assist me with solving how I can use 'this' to access the right context and develop a jQuery-like library that allows chaining.  I want 'learnQuery()' to function like jQuery(). I am having trouble chaining together the cssClass methods.

```
function learnQuery(elementSelector) {
  'use strict';
  var learnQueryContext = this;

  function cssPropProxy(property, value) {
    return cssProp(elementSelector, property, value);
  }

  function ajaxReqProxy(url, options) {
    return ajaxReq(url, options);
  }

  var cssClass = new CssClass();

  return {
    cssProp : cssPropProxy,
    ajaxReq : ajaxReqProxy,
    cssClass: {
      add: function(setClass) {
        cssClass.add(elementSelector, setClass);
        return learnQueryContext;
      },
      remove: function(deleteClass) {
        cssClass.remove(elementSelector, deleteClass);
        return learnQueryContext;
      },
      toggle: function(toggleClass) {
        cssClass.toggle(elementSelector, toggleClass);
        return learnQueryContext;
      },
      has: function(hasClass) {
        cssClass.has(elementSelector, hasClass);
        return learnQueryContext;
      }
    }
```

Comment: unless learnQuery is a constructor, `this` is probably `window` in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies Edwin and MarkM.  My main problem was with context.  I needed learnQuery(element).someMethod() to retain its context when chained with another method.  I'm still having problems fully understanding 'this' in JS, and how to ensure that it refers to the calling object - especially when the object is calling a function cutoff in a closure, like in my example.  My above example used the learnQueryContext variable to point out that I knew this was where my problem lay, and I couldn't figure out how to retain the context(i.e. the correct object) in order for the invoked function to act on it and return the desired value.  I was very close.  Instead of returning the long object as I did initially, I turned it into a variable that I could reference within itself, and then returned that variable.  This allowed it to retain the correct context.  See below:

```
function learnQuery(elementSelector) {
  'use strict';

  function cssPropProxy(property, value) {
    return cssProp(elementSelector, property, value);
  }

  function ajaxReqProxy(url, options) {
    return ajaxReq(url, options);
  }

  var cssClass = new CssClass();
  var dom = new Dom();
  var eventListener = new EventListener();

  var returnedContext = {
    cssProp : cssPropProxy,
    ajaxReq : ajaxReqProxy,
    cssClass: {
      add: function(setClass) {
        cssClass.add(elementSelector, setClass);
        return returnedContext;
      },
      remove: function(deleteClass) {
        cssClass.remove(elementSelector, deleteClass);
        return returnedContext;
      },
      toggle: function(toggleClass) {
        cssClass.toggle(elementSelector, toggleClass);
        return returnedContext;
      },
      has: function(hasClass) {
        return cssClass.has(elementSelector, hasClass);
      }
    }
  };
  return returnedContext;
}
```

Now I can use:

```
learnQuery('someElement').cssClass.add('someClass').cssClass.toggle('someClass');
```

and it works as expected.  cssClass is itself a constructor that I've defined elsewhere, along with its methods.  This code simply acts an interface to allow learnQuery() to use them.

Please let me know what you think and how else you might solve it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish would love to help you because I could also learn a bit more about jquery like libraries by teaching?

Comment: Hi Edwin, I actually am assisting on an open source project called learnQuery that will soon be released.  I'll be happy to provide a link as soon as it is out - which should be in the next couple of weeks.  It's purpose is to help developers better understand the ins and outs of the JavaScript language, so that is right up your alley I think.

Answer (score 1):

Yea I was playing with something like this before trying to learn the same thing. I still have this saved so see if you can understand this:

```
var $ = (function(){
    $ = function(selector){ return new MyQuery(selector); };

var MyQuery = function(selector){
    var nodes   = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    this.each   = Array.prototype.forEach.bind(nodes);
    this.map    = Array.prototype.map.bind(nodes);
    var len = this.length = nodes.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) this[i] = nodes[i];
};

$.fn = MyQuery.prototype = {
    addClass: function(classes){
        this.each(function(el){
            classes.forEach(function(className){
                el.classList.add(className);
            });
        });
        return this;
    },
    removeClass: function(classes){
        this.each(function(el){
            classes.forEach(function(className){
                el.classList.remove(className);
            });
        });
        return this;
    },
    addAttribute: function(newAttrib, value){
        this.each(function(el){
            el.setAttribute(newAttrib, value);
        });
        return this;
    },
    removeAttribute: function(attrib, value){
        this.each(function(el){
            el.removeAttribute(attrib);
        });
        return this;
    },
    remove: function(){
        this.each(function(el){
            el.remove();
        });
        return this;
    },
    on: function(type, callback){
        this.each(function(el){
            el.addEventListener(type, callback);
        });
        return this;
    },
    append: function(elem){
        this.each(function(el){
            el.appendChild(elem);
        });
        return this;
    },
    css: function(prop, value){
        this.each(function(el){
            el.style[prop] = value;
        });
        return this;
    }
}
return $;
})();
```

Comment: Please comment if you need more help

Comment: thx for the input Edwin.  I posted my solution below, which is quite simple and makes only very minor changes to the code.  I also explain more of what this particular code is doing and what I wanted to achieve.  Check it out and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to figure out what you want to happen with these functions.
`cssPropProxy()` returns `cssProp` but `cssProp` looks like is just a reference to `cssPropProxy()`.

The basic idea with chaining is that you return the object instance back. In your code it looks like you are returning a reference to the function. Here's a bare-bones chaining example that might help:

```
function chainingExample(startText){
    return {
        mytext: startText,

        append: function(text){
            this.mytext += text;
            return this;
            },
        show: function(){
            return this.mytext;
            }   
    }

}

console.log(chainingExample("hello").append(" there").append(" again").show());
/* results in: "hello there again" */
```

When used this way `this` points back to the returned object. It will look something like:

```
{ mytext: 'hello there again',
  append: [Function],
  show: [Function] }
```

Of course you can expand upon this, but the key idea is that the object you return needs to contain the functions you want to call. `this` and prototypes are one of the more confusing parts of JS. A really handy, short text is: 'You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes' by Kyle Simpson.

Comment: hi MarkM. thx for the input. I posted my own solution below as I solved my problem in a very simple way.  I also explain more clearly what my code is trying to achieve.  I agree it was hard to understand what I wanted based on the limited info in my question.  Please feel free to leave any comments.